# jaxb idref string adapter

Tags: java, jaxb

I'm using a standard xml schema, called isosts, I need to convert schema to java class using jaxb. In this xml schema, a lot of elements have attribute rid as type xs:IDREFS `<xs:attribute name="rid" type="xs:IDREFS">`. Jaxb converts xs:IDREFS to be list of Objects.

For my need, I want jaxb to make type xs:IDREFS to be just java string type in all the generated java class. And during marshall/unmarshall time, the value of attribute rid should all be handled as string. Since this is a standard schema, I have to customize jaxb. I'm not sure if this can be done in jaxb binding or adapter and how to do it. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This binding file (let's call it "binding.xjb) forces the type to String:

```
<bindings xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb"
      xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
      xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2000/10/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:schemaLocation=" http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb
                           http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/jaxb/bindingschema_2_0.xsd"
      version="2.1">

<bindings schemaLocation="SomeSchemaName.xsd" node="/xs:schema">
    <bindings node="//xs:attribute[@name='rid']">
        <property>
          <baseType>
            <javaType name="java.lang.String"></javaType>
          </baseType>
        </property>
    </bindings>
</bindings>

</bindings>
```

Compile the schema using

```
xjc -b binding.xjb SomeSchemaName.xsd
```